# Generating dynamic dropdown list in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I need to generate the second dropdownlist based on a choice of the first.

**View in _form.php:**

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::dropDownList('category_id','', Category::allCategory(),
     array(
     'ajax' => array(
     'type'=>'POST', //request type
     'url'=>CController::createUrl('subcategory/dynamicSubCategories'), //url to call.
     //Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
     'update'=>'#subcategory_id', //selector to update
     //'data'=>'js:javascript statement'
     //leave out the data key to pass all form values through
     )));

     //empty since it will be filled by the other dropdown
     echo CHtml::dropDownList('subcategory_id','', array());
?>
```

Also I created the controler:
**SubcategoryController.php**

```
public function actionDynamicSubCategories() {
        $data = Subcategory::model()->findAll('category_id=:category_id', 
                array(':category_id' => (int)$_POST['category_id']));

        $data = CHtml::listData($data, 'id', 'title');
        foreach ($data as $value => $name) {
            echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name), true);
        }
    }
```

I registered the rules for performance of this action in the same controler:
function accessRules

```
array('allow', // deny all users
            'actions' => array('DynamicSubCategories'),
            'users' => array('@'),
        ),
```

The table 'category' has structure: **id, title, position** and Category::allCategory() return:

```
return CHtml::listData($models, 'id', 'title');
```

The table 'subcategory' has structure: **id, title, category_id**.

Unfortunately, the inquiry is carried out but in the second dropdownlist is displayed nothing, prompt that I made not correctly?

Result:
[image: Dropdownlist's]

Comment: Look at `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail`, where is no ajax params, only HTMLOptions. You have to organize `ajax` on change event of `select#category_id`

Comment: I need an AJAX to change the second list automatically when in the first value changes is necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail`, where is no ajax params, only HTMLOptions. You have to organize `ajax` on change event of `select#category_id`:

like that:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList('category_id','', Category::allCategory(), array('onchange' => 'getSubCategory(this.value)'));
?>
<script>function getSubCategory(val) {
$.ajax({
     type :'POST', //request type
     url : '<?php echo CController::createUrl('subcategory/dynamicSubCategories')?>',
     success : function(data) {
         $('#subcategory_id').html(data);
     }
};</script>
```

Comment: I made everything as wrote, but the situation didn't change. http://pastebin.com/H9mP4waP

Answer (score 0):

*SOLVED*

**_form.php**

```
<?php 
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id');
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('category_id','', Category::allCategory(),
         array(
         'ajax' => array(
         'type'=>'POST', //request type
         'url'=>CController::createUrl('subcategory/dynamicSubCategories'), //url to call.
         //Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
         'update'=>'#subcategory_id', //selector to update
         //'data'=>'js:javascript statement'
         //leave out the data key to pass all form values through
         )));
    echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); 

     echo $form->labelEx($model,'subcategory_id');
     echo CHtml::dropDownList('subcategory_id','', array());
     echo $form->error($model,'subcategory_id');
?>
```

**SubcategoryController.php**

```
public function actionDynamicSubCategories() {
    echo $_POST['ajax'];
    $data = Subcategory::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('category_id' => $_POST['category_id']));

    $data = CHtml::listData($data, 'id', 'title');
    foreach ($data as $value => $name) {
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name), true);
    }
}
```